# Python exercise remove from list based on another list grade

Tags: python, list

I am learning Python, This is my current exercise:

*Write a program that stores the subjects of a course (for example:Mathematics, Physics, Chemistry, History and Language) in a list, ask the user for the grade they have taken in each subject and remove from the list approved subjects. At the end the program must show on screen the subjects that the user has to repeat.*

I have the following code:

```
classes = ['math', 'chemistry', 'History', 'Marketing']
gradelist = []

for i in range(len(classes)):
    grade = int(input(f"Please provide your grade in {classes[i]}: "))
    gradelist.append(grade)
print("These are the classes you need to take again because of failure:")
for i in range(len(classes)):
    for y in range(len(gradelist)):
        if gradelist[y] > 69:
            classes.remove(classes[i])
            gradelist.remove(gradelist[y])
        print(f"{classes[i]} Grade : {gradelist[y]}")
```

Can anyone please help me, its not working. I can Enter the grades but I am missing something on removing the passed subjects and grades above 70.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a lot safer to not to modify the list that you're iterating over. And it makes sense in this case, because the list of courses to retake is a much more "local" quantity than the list of possible courses. So all the list reduction here takes place on a local copy of the subject list, and since there's no given requirement to hold on to the grade, it's just used for that reduction.

```py
subjects = "Mathematics Physics Chemistry History Language".split()
passgrade = 70

retakes = subjects.copy()
for subject in subjects:
    grade = int(input(f'What grade achieved in {subject}? '))
    if grade >= passgrade:
        retakes.remove(subject)
if retakes:
    print('You need to retake:')
    print(*retakes, sep='\n')
else:
    print('No retakes needed')
```

Comment: @AndresRamirez Let me know if you need any further explanation about how this works.

Comment: Just a small note with `copy`. In this context, it is perfectly fine. But for future reference if it is used,  the `copy` here is shallow. So, for example if you were dealing with something like `[[1, 2, 3], 5, [3,4,5]]` and you did a copy on that, what would happen once you change one of the inner lists, it would change it in the other list you copied to as well. To not have this behaviour you can use deepcopy. More info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

Comment: @idjaw - Agreed, although the trap of referencing the same list under two different guises - and getting highly confusing errors - is practically a Python rite of passage. :-)

Comment: @Joffan lol fair. And a good time to note that I don't miss "school" programming questions at all. :)

Comment: not effective, `list.remove` is O(n). Instead more wise to add "retakes" elements to the list

Comment: @Reishin removing elements was in the exercise specification. Personally I would be tempted to generate `retakes` with a comprehension in this case. Real-world use would demand a better UI though.

Comment: oh, yes ..indeed

Answer (score 0):

I mean, you remove an item from `classes` with `classes.remove(classes[i])` and then immediately try to print the item with the same index: `classes[i]`. Doesn't this seem odd?

You deleted, say, `classes[3]`, and then immediately tried to print `classes[3]`. But `classes` now has one less element! Imagine you had `classes = [0,1,2,3]`, then you deleted `classes[3]`, so now `classes = [0,1,2]`. Wait, `classes[3]` isn't a valid index anymore, so you'll get `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Even worse, if `classes` has more elements, like `classes = [0,1,2,3,4]`, then after deleting `classes[3]` it will become `classes = [0,1,2,4]`, so now you get a *new* `classes[3] == 4`!

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your program use zip. This will help you iterate over two lists. Then you can unpack these.

```
classes = ['math', 'chemistry', 'History', 'Marketing']
gradelist = [int(input(f"Please provide your grade in {classes[i]}: ")) for i in range(len(classes))]
print("These are the classes you need to take again because of failure:")
newGradeList = []
newClassList = []
for classX,grades in zip(classes,gradelist):
    if grades <= 69:
        newGradeList.append(grades)
        newClassList.append(classX)
        print(f"{classX} Grade : {grades}")
```

output/input

```
Please provide your grade in math: 20
Please provide your grade in chemistry: 40
Please provide your grade in History: 70
Please provide your grade in Marketing: 80
These are the classes you need to take again because of failure:
math Grade : 20
chemistry Grade : 40
History Grade : 70
Marketing Grade : 80
```

Also just to explain why you are encountering, never mutate/modify lists you are iterating over. This can cause weird things to happen. Instead, you can create new lists.
Lastly I suggest using a dictionary in this case.

```
classes = ['math', 'chemistry', 'History', 'Marketing']
gradelist = [int(input(f"Please provide your grade in {classes[i]}: ")) for i in range(len(classes))]
data = {clas:grade for clas,grade in zip(classes,gradelist)}
print("These are the classes you need to take again because of failure:")
for k,v in data.items():
    if v <= 69:
        print(f"{k} Grade : {v}")
```

Comment: Try inputting `80, 90, 1, 2` for the grades. You'll get `Grade : [90, 1, 2]` as the result, which is incorrect because the 90 should've been deleted, but it wasn't.

Comment: I'm not getting that output. I've gotten History Grade : 1
Marketing Grade : 2

Comment: Oh yeah. You posted your comment before my edit. My bad.

Comment: is here really any need in tuple list to dict conversion?  (last sample)

Comment: Sorry what do you mean @Reishin?

Comment: I mean, why the `data` variable even needed, just iterate through `zip`

Comment: data is a dictionary. I'm storing classes as a key and grades as a value.

Comment: you already storing  the data in 2 lists, why to create third entity to store the same?

Comment: not better, you consuming more memory for no benefits, not even telling about additional cycle with no reasons. If that list would contain 1 million items?    Or construct the dictionary from the start or do not waste resources for meaningless transformations